# How to return matching column of original data frame after producing a new dataframe with dplyr

Tags: r

I am trying to find out the manipulate my original data frame (BLAST) to find out the max values of selected columns.

```
head(BLAST)
     qseqid                 sseqid staxids  pident bitscore   evalue length mismatch qstart qend
1:  k127_70 ref|NZ_MCGG01000042.1|   28181  73.930    102.0 1.57e-20    257       65    228  483
2:  k127_84 ref|NZ_FXXN01000027.1| 1979370  80.690    110.0 5.76e-23    145       24     70  212
3:  k127_84       ref|NC_007626.1|  342108  78.621     93.5 5.80e-18    145       27     70  212
4:  k127_86     gb|PEAC01000057.1| 2032654 100.000     62.1 2.41e-08     33        0    408  440
5: k127_311 ref|NZ_LWQU01000152.1| 1437059  72.709    292.0 3.63e-77    993      227     30 1006
6: k127_311     ref|NZ_FO538765.1| 1288970  72.778    222.0 4.83e-56    720      172     20  727
   qcovhsp qcovs
1:      53    53
2:      47    47
3:      47    47
4:       8     8
5:      50    50
6:      36    36
                                                                                                              taxonomy
1:        Proteobacteria,Alphaproteobacteria,Rhodospirillales,Rhodospirillaceae,Magnetovibrio,Magnetovibrio blakemorei
2:    Proteobacteria,Alphaproteobacteria,Rhodospirillales,Rhodospirillaceae,Magnetospirillum,Magnetospirillum sp. 15-1
3:  Proteobacteria,Alphaproteobacteria,Rhodospirillales,Rhodospirillaceae,Magnetospirillum,Magnetospirillum magneticum
4:                                                                Nitrospirae,NA,NA,NA,NA,Nitrospirae bacterium MYbin6
5: Proteobacteria,Alphaproteobacteria,Rhodospirillales,Rhodospirillaceae,Magnetospirillum,Magnetospirillum moscoviense
6:            Proteobacteria,Alphaproteobacteria,Rhodospirillales,Rhodospirillaceae,Magnetospira,Magnetospira sp. QH-2
```

I have created another dataframe (Max.BLAST) to obtain the maximum value for certain column, and group it by taxonomy.

```
Max.BLAST <- BLAST %>%
  group_by(taxonomy) %>%
  summarize(evalue = max(evalue),
            bitscore = max(bitscore),
            pident = max(pident))


head(Max.BLAST)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  taxonomy                                                                     evalue bitscore pident
  <chr>                                                                         <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Candidatus Omnitrophica,NA,NA,NA,Candidatus Omnitrophus,Candidatus Omni…    1.00e-6     1118    100
2 Candidatus Omnitrophica,NA,NA,NA,NA,Candidatus Omnitrophica bacterium       1.00e-6      630    100
3 NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,bacterium FH-1                                               8.27e-7      169    100
4 NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,magneto-ovoid bacterium MO-1                                 9.95e-7     1474    100
5 Nitrospirae,NA,NA,NA,NA,Nitrospirae bacterium                               1.00e-6     1110    100
6 Nitrospirae,NA,NA,NA,NA,Nitrospirae bacterium MYbin3                        9.95e-7      893    100
```

How do I obtain the matching "qseqid" column for Max.BLAST dataframe?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Hi,
I don't know the details of your data, but probably what you want is not exactly possible:
The row for which evalue is maximal could have a different `qseqid` than the row for which `bitscore` is maximal.

Comment: Dear @ Cettt,

The values are supposed to match each other. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Max.BLAST <- BLAST %>%
  group_by(taxonomy) %>%
  mutate(evalue = max(evalue),
            bitscore = max(bitscore),
            pident = max(pident))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
Max.BLAST <- BLAST %>%
  group_by(taxonomy) %>%
  summarize(evalue = max(evalue),
            bitscore = max(bitscore),
            pident = max(pident)) %>%
    semi_join(BLAST, . , by = c("taxonomy", "evalue", "bitscore", "pident")) %>%
    select(qseqid, taxonomy, evalue, bitscore, pident) %>%
    distinct()
```

Comment: Dear @ Cettt, unfortunately that did not work for me. 

dim(Max.BLAST)
[1] 47  4

A <- BLAST %>%
+   group_by(taxonomy) %>%
+   summarize(evalue = max(evalue),
+             bitscore = max(bitscore),
+             pident = max(pident)) %>%
+   semi_join(BLAST, . , by = c("taxonomy", "evalue")) %>%
+   select(qseqid, taxonomy, evalue, bitscore, pident)

dim(A)
[1] 173   5

I only want the 47 taxonomies, and to retrieve their matching qseqid.

Thank you for looking through this.

Comment: Dear @Cettt,

Unfortunately, that did not work either.

B <- BLAST %>%
  group_by(taxonomy) %>%
  summarize(evalue = max(evalue),
            bitscore = max(bitscore),
            pident = max(pident)) %>%
  semi_join(BLAST, . , by = c("taxonomy", "evalue", "bitscore", "pident")) %>%
  select(qseqid, taxonomy, evalue, bitscore, pident) %>%
  distinct()

dim(B)
[1] 0 5

Comment: can share the output of `dput(BLAST)` inside your question (not as a comment).
If your data is too large select an appropriate subset.

Answer (score 0):

@Cettt's answer above should work, but here's another solution without joining :

```
Max.BLAST <- BLAST %>%
    group_by(taxonomy) %>%
    mutate(is_max = evalue == max(evalue)) %>%
    filter(is_max == TRUE) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Since you said that the maximum values are supposed to match each other, basically you are searching, for each group of `taxonomy`, for the line which matches the maximum value of any of the variables, so you create a dummy to match that maximum value, and then you filter on that dummy. Obviously you can aggregate the two operations into one (I added a fake data to make it reproducible) :

```
set.seed(10042019)
nrows <- 50

BLAST <- data.frame(
  id = paste0('id_', 1:nrows),
  taxonomy = sample(letters[1:5], size = nrows, replace = T),
  evalue = runif(nrows),
  bitscore = rnorm(nrows),
  stringsAsFactors = F
) 

head(BLAST)

BLAST %>%
  group_by(taxonomy) %>%
  filter(evalue == max(evalue)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

If you want to be sure that it matches all maxima, you can use a `filter_at` :

```
BLAST <- mutate(BLAST, bitscore = evalue * 2.5)
BLAST %>%
  group_by(taxonomy) %>%
  filter_at(vars(evalue, bitscore), all_vars(. == max(.))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Note that this last solution may yield an empty data.frame if the maxima are not reached for the same line !